# Formal way to add a set to an existing collection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If we have an existing collection of sets $\{G_\alpha\}$ (possibly uncountable) and a $X$ that we would like to add to the collection, what is the formal way to do this?

Note that I'm not looking for $\{G_\alpha\} \cup X$, which would contain the members of $X$. Would it be something like $\{\{G_\alpha\}\} \cup \{X\}$?

Comment: (edited for clarity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is neither, but rather $\{G_\alpha\}\cup\{X\}$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. It seems I was confusing little union $\cup$ with big union $\bigcup$. Is it correct that $\{G_\alpha\} \cup \{X\} = \bigcup\{\{G_\alpha\}, \{X\}\}$?

Comment: That is, when $\bigcup$ is defined as in Jech, for example.

Comment: Yes. $\bigcup S=\{x\mid \exists s\in S. x\in s\}$, so in the case $S=\{\{G_\alpha\},\{X\}\}$ this is exactly $\{G_\alpha\}\cup\{X\}$.